# limit resolution with arcsin function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

This o sth exercise:
$\lim_{x\to 1} {\frac{2\arcsin(x)-\pi}{x-1}}$

Considerint $x\to 1^+$ My first move was try to substitute $x-1$ with $y$, obtaining:

$\lim_{y\to 0^+} {\frac{2\arcsin(y+1)-\pi}{y}}$

and using the sum formula for $\arcsin(a+b)$ I haven't gained nothig usefull, the same trying to divide factors by $\arcsin(x)$...

It's the last exercise i've to do and i'm stucked, any suggestion?

I've to solve this limit with only algebric passages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x=\sin\left(y+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\quad\Rightarrow\quad y=\arcsin(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}$

$$\lim_{x\to 1} {\frac{2\arcsin(x)-\pi}{x-1}}=\lim_{y\to 0} {\frac{2y}{\sin\left(y+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-1}}=\lim_{y\to 0} {\frac{2y}{\cos(y)-1}}=\lim_{y\to 0} {\frac{2}{\frac{\cos\left(y\right)-1}{y}}}=\infty\ .$$

Comment: Thankyou but i guess we have to explain that in x->1+ arcsen is not defined and the limit is not valid... however this is the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$f(x)=2\arcsin x$$
then
$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{2\arcsin(x)-\pi}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{f(x)-f(1)}{x-1}=f'(1)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\bigg|_{x\to1}=\infty$$

Comment: Thankyou, but for the resolution i can use only algebric passages, not differential or other